# Postfix spaming through my server

Tags: postfix

I was browsing the logs and I noticed the undesired mails are sent through my server. How to prevent this?

Log

```
Jun 24 18:29:31 mail postfix/pickup[13853]: 6BD3D17012CB: uid=65534 from= edmondo@ferrettispa.it>

Jun 24 18:29:31 mail postfix/cleanup[13901]: 6BD3D17012CB: message-id=<00bb01ce70f9$def3a480$201e000a@69.lv>

Jun 24 18:29:31 mail postfix/qmgr[13854]: 6BD3D17012CB: from=<edmondo@ferrettispa.it>, size=1145, nrcpt=1 (queue active)

Jun 24 18:29:33 mail postfix/smtp[13906]: 6BD3D17012CB: to=<carlo.dago@istruzione.it>, relay=mx.sidi.istruzione.it[89.97.132.171]:25, delay=2.5, delays=0.14/0/0.14/2.3, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as CB89D50096)

Jun 24 18:29:33 mail postfix/qmgr[13854]: 6BD3D17012CB: removed
```

main.cf

```
smtpd_sender_restrictions =     hash:/etc/postfix/access,
                                permit_mynetworks,
                                reject_non_fqdn_sender,
                                reject_unknown_sender_domain,
                                permit
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access

smtpd_recipient_restrictions = check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,
                               check_sender_access hash:/etc/postfix/access,
                               permit_mynetworks,
                               permit_sasl_authenticated,
                               reject_non_fqdn_hostname,
                               reject_invalid_hostname,
                                reject_non_fqdn_sender,
                                reject_unknown_sender_domain
                                reject_non_fqdn_recipient,
                                reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
                                reject_unauth_destination,
                               reject_unknown_recipient_domain,
#                              check_policy_service inet:127.0.0.1:10023,
                               reject_rbl_client list.dsbl.org,
                                reject_rbl_client sbl.spamhaus.org,
                                reject_rbl_client cbl.abuseat.org,
                                reject_rbl_client dul.dnsbl.sorbs.net,
```

Answer (score 1):

Your mail server has been cracked. Notice the "pickup" service in the log? That means that message has been locally injected (by uid 65534), and not received via tcp/25 SMTPD port, so no amount of SMTPD restrictions will have any effect.

You could disable **pickup** service in master.cf, but that would disable all local clients sending mail, and attacker could circumvent it by connecting to localhost:25 instead. Then you'd also have to disable relaying ALL mails from localhost (by removing all entries that match that host from **mynetworks** in main.cf - anything that starts with "127." or "[::1]" meaning localhost, as well as any other IPs/hostnames matching your host)

(the real answer is to fix the bug through which attacker gained access to your system, and remove any backdoors)